# Redirect to controller/view when dropdownlist changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET MVC application.  I have a Html.DropDownList.  I want to redirect to another controller when the selection is changed, and want the key of the selected dropdownlist item as a param in the URL.

How should I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do this with Javascript; I would recommend using jquery.  Also, put the dropdown in a form, method of get and action of the controller/action URL.  Then set the click event to post the form.

So, your HTML will be something like:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/Controller/Action" method="get">
    <select id="mySelect">...</select>
</form>
```

And in jquery something like:

```
$('#mySelect').change(function() { $('#myForm').submit(); });
```

Note you can use the Html.Form() helper to create the form.  Also, I'd recommend having a submit button on the form, which you can hide with javascript.  Then people who have JS disabled still have a way to submit the form.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use JavaScript to do this:

```
<select onchange="OnChangeEvent(this);">
 <option value="1">option 1</option>
 <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 function OnChangeEvent(dropDownElement){
  var selectedValue = dropDownElement.options[dropDownElement.selectedIndex].value;
  document.location = "/some/mvc/route/" + selectedValue;
 }
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: If you use jQuery, use Chris Shaffers solution