# Redirect to MVC ActionResult with Parameters when DropDownList option is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, razor

I am using MVC to create part of a website. In one of my Views I have a `DropDownList`. When a new drop down list option is selected, or in other words `onchange`, I want my page to be redirected to a specific Controller `ActionResult`. I am able to get to `MyAction` ActionResult if there are no parameters, however I can't figure out how to send in the needed parameters.

My Controller Action:

```
public virtual ActionResult MyAction(int param1, int param2)
{
    return View();
}
```

My DropDownList in View:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
        "viewDataItem", Model.MyEnumerableList as SelectList, 
        new { onchange = @"
            var form = document.forms[0];
            form.action='MyAction';
            form.submit();" 
        } )
```

The above code calls MyAction, however it does not send in the parameters. Is there a way to somehow add the parameters to this code?

Another thought was to somehow use `@{Response.Redirect(@Url.Action("MyAction", "myController", new { param1 = 2, param2= 3 }));}` as my DropDownList action since Response.Redirect allows me to redirect to MyAction with parameters. Is there a way to somehow make onchanged =  Response.Redirect?

The tried making onchange equal the response, but the nothing happens when I change my option:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
        "name", Model.MyEnumerableList as SelectList,
        new
        {
            onchange = {Response.Redirect(@Url.Action("MyAction", "controllerName", new { param1 = 5, param2 = 3 }));}
        })
```

In short, how do I call an ActionResult with parameters whenever my DropDownList option is changed?

Similar questions were asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530850/redirect-to-controller-view-when-dropdownlist-changed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332225/checkbox-oncheck-redirect-to-actionresult-in-mvc), but the answers provide in those links all use JavaScript and I don't know how to use JS with cshtml. I tried some of those answers, but none of them solved my problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify on the onchange event a javascript function and inside that function:

```
var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("MyAction", "controllerName", new { param1=5, param2=2 }))';
```

and then:

```
window.location = url;
```

Finally the code should be:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "viewDataItem", Model.MyEnumerableList as SelectList, 
    new { onchange = "SelectionChanged()" 
    } )

<script>
 function SelectionChanged()
 {
  var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("MyAction", "controllerName", new { param1=5, param2=2 }))';
  window.location = url;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Where would I add `window.location = url`?

Comment: In the js function that will be execute when the selection changed, all js code will be inside that function

Comment: I don't have an JS code?? Are you refering to the onchanged code?

Comment: Check my answer again, I put all the code you need.

Comment: It almost works. The URL generated though is adding `amp;` in between the two parameters and so it is not getting the second parameter.

Comment: Use `Html.Raw` like this: `@Html.Raw(Url.Action("MyAction", "controllerName", new { param1=5, param2=2 }))`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to somehow add the parameters to this code?

Sure, there are many ways. One of them would be:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
        "viewDataItem", Model.MyEnumerableList as SelectList, 
        new { onchange = @"
            var form = document.forms[0];
            form.action='MyAction?param1=5&param2=3';
            form.submit(); /*Just make sure that form 'method' attribute is set to 'post'*/" 
        } )
```

But a much better way is described in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530850/redirect-to-controller-view-when-dropdownlist-changed) you mentioned.

> Is there a way to somehow make onchanged = Response.Redirect?

Not the way you're trying to use it. `onchanged` is a javascript event, and javascript knows nothing about `Response` property or other MVC server-side stuff.