# How to handle different fields for different dropdownlist values in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my first Mvc project so my apologies if i am asking something dumb.
I have a `DropDownList` that sets the kind of item. For each kind there are a few fields that need to change according to the selected type.

How can i know if the post back was fired from the drop down list?
At the controller i need to know if the method was called because the `DropDownList` changed, and in that case i need to change the dependent fields, or, if the user press save and i have to capture and store all data.

The best approach i found so far is to send an parameter on the post-back fired from the `DropDownList`. Still i need to clear the parameter after the post back and i am stuck there.

This looks a bit more complicated that it should for something i think is common, so probably Mvc should provide a better approach but i can't find one.

Comment: `<select>` elements don't trigger form posts by default.  What's actually triggering the post?  Perhaps you can skip the issue entirely and just update the fields client-side instead of reloading the whole page?  At the very least, the post to get updated values and the post to save the form should be to different controller actions.

Comment: I used the approach at this post :https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060294/2700303

Comment: Why?  Take a step back here and determine specifically what you're trying to accomplish.  What do you want this form to do?  It sounds like you just want to update some values on the page when a `<select>` changes, which can be done client-side without the need to reload the page.  What's the actual goal here?

Comment: The fields i need to use depend entirely on database configurations, so i can't have a controller for each type. All the custom fields are build into a dynamic table that renders bellow the page fixed fields.

Comment: You'll need to submit a form or make an AJAX request to get back your new data. The tutorial has an example with a form submission https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search#adding-markup-to-the-index-view-to-support-search-by-genre

Comment: @ByteArtisan: You don't need "a controller for each type".  What it sounds like you do need is a controller action for posting the selected item and getting the data associated with that item.  Ideally this would be done with AJAX instead of reloading the page.

Comment: Yes, i think that would separate things. Edit post back method would only have to save the page. Thanks.